# Почему calc запускается а regedit нет

Tags: java

Windows 10. Пробую из Java запускать сторонние программы. 
Почему калькулятор запускается, а другие программы не хотят? (Через Win+R работает любая из перечисленных)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    //processBuilder.command("regedit"); // Не запускается
    processBuilder.command("calc");     // !!!Работает!!!!
    //processBuilder.command("cmd");    // Не запускается
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
}
```

Comment: Потому, что regedit требует админских прав. Подробнее здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041509/elevating-a-processbuilder-process-via-uac

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А cmd почему не запускается? У меня регедит стартует, а консоль нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик Потому, что он аттачится к текущей консоли https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954194/start-cmd-by-using-processbuilder